# Remove code blocks from read estimation in Jekyll Liquid

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

In my blog based on Jekyll I included a read estimation similar to the one on Medium. However I don't want it to include code blocks which I use a lot in the article. The snippet looks like this:

```
<span class="post-meta">
    {{ post.content | number_of_words | divided_by:180 }} min read
</span>
```

I already used `strip_html` but this did not remove the code blocks from counting.

Bonus if you also have suggestion to count the number of lines of code in the article so I would be able to post something similar to this:

```
<span class="post-meta">
    {{ post.content | number_of_words | ? | divided_by:180 }} min read and {{ ? }} lines of code
</span>
```